# Text wont stay in its own "space"?

Tags: html, css

Using the position tag in the css code is not really making a difference for each item.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="headerbuttons"><p>HOME</p></div>
<div id="headerbuttons"><p>DATABASE</p></div>
<div id="headerbuttons"><p>HOW TO INSTALL</p></div>
<div id="headerbuttons"><p>OTHER SOLUTIONS</p></div>
```

CSS:

```
#headerbuttons {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
#headerbuttons:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
}
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/T8pUR/

Comment: And what was the intention behind using `position: absolute`? As it stands the CSS is doing exactly what you told it to do, positioning the elements absolutely with reference to the position of the nearest non-static element. Also, invalid HTML (an `id` ***must be unique within the document***), if you want to address/group multiple elements use `class`.

Comment: You can have only 1 id headerbuttons. Also you need to specify the position you want them to appear. For example top,bottom, right, left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is a solution to your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/VGP4K/

Basically I've removed `position: absolute` from your code and replaced it with `float: left`. Also, I've removed the `ID` tags and replaced them with `class` tags.

Remember, `ID`s are meant to be unique within your HTML. When you want to apply a repeating pattern of style, use a `class`.

**Update** to help you with the centering: http://jsfiddle.net/VGP4K/2/

Comment: Do you know how I might center them? Text Align property isn't working for me.

Comment: Using text-align or the margin properties, they will each go on there own line. http://jsfiddle.net/VGP4K/1/

Comment: I've updated my answer providing some hints. Not sure if this is the desired look as not a lot of info is provided :)

Comment: Oh, I was trying to center them. Can't understand why it doesn't work on a server compared to posting on jsfiddle. http://dll-download.us/ is where I uploaded it to.

Comment: Oh, must be my DNS Cache.

Comment: Hey, if you meant that thing i showed you in the picture, then use this code: http://jsfiddle.net/VGP4K/3/ . I've changed some stuff in the DOM and then took a screenshot, since I wasnt sure that's what you needed.

Comment: Hey Zub, is there an easier way to make the text go a bit smoother? As in when it zooms in, it kinda re-sizes it bit. Not sure if you understand me. Should I just increase the zoom time?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position: absolute`.

If you want to make them appear side-by-side, add `display:inline-block`;

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you wanted to do is to position them next to each other.

Using `position:absolute` effectively removes them out of the document flow. Thus they each occupy 0 space and the browser happily overlays them.

To fix this issue remove the `position:absolute` and consider using something like `float:left`.

I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T8pUR/2/) to showcase it.